# Как обрезать строку в golang до первого вхождения одного из разделителей?

Tags: строки, golang

Пусть есть некоторая строка "my.str!"
Необходимо извлечь "my."

Comment: а результате что должно быть?

Comment: какой должен быть результат, если строка будет вида `"my.str!my.t"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам действительно нужно делать со строкой что-то относительно сложное (а вопрос читается так, что разделителей может быть несколько разных) то вам подойдут регулярные выражения.

В данном примере кроме разделителя `.` в выражение добавлены разделители `,` и `-`.

```
var r = regexp.MustCompile(`^(.*?[.,-]{1})(.*)`) // регулярное выражение
// нет необходимости парсить регулярное выражение каждый раз при вызове функции
// достаточно объявить статическую переменную

func f(s string) string {
    split := r.FindStringSubmatch(s)
    if len(split) < 2 {
        return ""
    }
    return split[1]
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/h8vk4rlH4Qa

Проверить работу вашей регулярки на Go вы можете [здесь.](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Да, исследовав библиотеку strings я пришел к тому же выводу. Тот самый случай, когда кроме регулярки - никак.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [`strings.SplitAfterN`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#SplitAfterN):

```go
func f(s string) (prefix string) {
    var strs = strings.SplitAfterN(s, ".", 2)

    if len(strs) == 1 {
        return ""
    }

    return strs[0]
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/afzqaH5yazB